# Is it possible to use write.table() and ddply, together?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data.frame like:

```
a <- c(1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10)
df <- data.frame(a,rnorm(100))
```

And I want to be able to write a csv file for each value of x. Is it possible to do this with ddply?

I can already do this with a for loop in a few lines... but I'm curious if it's possible to do it with ddply.

```
for (x in 1:nrow(unique(df["a"]))) {
tmp <- unique(df["a"])
tmp2 <- paste(tmp[x,],".csv", sep="")
write.table(subset(df, a == tmp[a,], drop=T),file=tmp2, sep=",", row.names=F)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing from Joshua's answer, the `plyr` function to use is `d_ply` which does not expect to return anything. You can do something like this:

```
d_ply(df, .(a),
      function(sdf) write.csv(sdf,
                              file=paste(sdf$a[[1]],".csv",sep="")))
```

The `file` argument to `write.csv` is constructed such that each subset gets a different filename.

Answer (score 1):

It's *possible* to do it with `ddply`, but that is not what the function was designed for.  From the `plyr` documentation:

> All plyr functions use the same
>   split-apply-combine strategy...

You want to split the data.frame and apply a function but you don't want to *return* anything, so `ddply` will throw an error if you don't return something that can be combined into a data.frame.