# Write list of data.frames to separate CSV files with lapply

Tags: r

The question says it all - I want to take a list object full of data.frames and write each data.frame to a separate .csv file where the name of the .csv file corresponds to the name of the list object.

Here's a reproducible example and the code I've written thus far.

```
df <- data.frame(
    var1 = sample(1:10, 6, replace = TRUE)
    , var2 = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 6, replace = TRUE)
    , theday = c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
)

df.daily <- split(df, df$theday) #Split into separate days

lapply(df.daily, function(x){write.table(x, file = paste(names(x), ".csv", sep = ""), row.names = FALSE, sep = ",")})
```

And here is the top of the error message that R spits out

```
Error: Results must have one or more dimensions.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3411429/271616

Comment: @Joshua - dar, Google search fail. I should go home now. Feel free to close this one.

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate. Your error is telling that you are passing more than one string to write.table as a file name. names(x) returns all colnames of a data frame.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
sapply(names(df.daily), 
 function (x) write.table(df.daily[[x]], file=paste(x, "txt", sep=".") )   )
```

You should see the names ("1", "2", "3") spit out one by one, but the NULLs are the evidence that the side-effect of writing to disk files was done. (Edit: changed [] to [[]].)

Comment: Thanks for base  R solution and the more succinct way to use `paste`.

Comment: I think there should be `df.daily[[x]]`.

Comment: Both df.daily[x] and df.daily[[x]] give the same result on my machine. I guess I can see the logic of your suspicion, though.

Comment: I think the reason that both forms succeed is that write.table coerces to data.frame class with as.data.frame() if the object is not one to start with and that will succeed if the object is a list with one dataframe.

Comment: For me result is not the same. Columns names in `[]` version have prefix (e.g. `X1.var1`), in `[[]]` version don't.

Answer (score 11):

You could use `mapply`:

```
mapply(
  write.table,
  x=df.daily, file=paste(names(df.daily), "txt", sep="."),
  MoreArgs=list(row.names=FALSE, sep=",")
)
```

There is [thread about similar problem on `plyr` mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/manipulatr/browse_thread/thread/29fd3f6142c3421c/5473655ddca35e39).

Answer (score 7):

A couple of things:

`laply` performs operations on a list. What you're looking for is `d_ply`. And you don't have to break it up by day, you can let `plyr` do that for you. Also, I would not use names(x) as that returns all of the column names of a data.frame.

```
d_ply(df, .(theday), function(x) write.csv(x, file=paste(x$theday,".csv",sep=""),row.names=F))
```

Comment: I always forget about the "_" plyr functions for some reason. This will do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: this solution doesn;t work for me. I get an error message as follows: Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used