# Exporting a list of dataframes as csv

Tags: r, list, csv, export

I have a list of dataframes which I want to export as csv. I tried :

```
for (i in listofdf){
  write.csv(listofdf[i], file = paste(names(listofdf)[i],".csv", sep=""), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

and got : `Error in listofdf[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'`. I [read](https://www.programmingr.com/r-error-messages/invalid-subscript-type-list-in-r/) that I am feeding a list data type into a process that expects a vector, and tried to apply the given solution : `unlist(listofdf)`, but all I got is a massive list of numeric values that I don't know how to deal with.

Then I tried a solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209512/write-list-of-data-frames-to-separate-csv-files-with-lapply), that works with the given example, but when I try to apply :

```
sapply(names(listofdf),
       function (x) write.table(listofdf[x],
                                file = paste(names(listofdf)[x],".csv", sep=""),
                                row.names = FALSE))
```

but when I try it, it only exports one file named NA.csv. Do you know how to make any of those solutions work?

Comment: Do they have to be a csv? If not, `writexl::write_xlsx` will write each element of a list to a sheet in an excel workbook. It's vectorized so you won't need a loop and it uses the list name as the sheetname.

Comment: Refer to elements of a list with `[[`, not `[`.

Comment: Also try `listofdf[[i]]` in your code

Comment: Csv is the format I'm used to but I can try something else. Same issue with one or two `[`
`listofdf[[i]]` gives the same error (invalid subscript type 'list') but `listofdf[[1]]` works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is how you're indexing your `list` object and `names(listofdf)[i]` isn't doing what you're thinking. Try This:

```
listofdf <- list(a = iris, b = iris, c = iris)

for (i in seq_along(listofdf)){
  write.csv(listofdf[[i]], file = paste0(names(listofdf)[i], ".csv"), row.names = F)
}
```

Side note: the default separator for `paste` is a space. So you're putting a space before the ".csv" extension with your code. `paste0` does not paste strings together with a space.

---

Alternatively, as mentioned you can use `writexlsx` by simply:

```
library(writexl)

write_xlsx(listofdfs, "output.xlsx")
```

This will create a file called "output.xlsx" with sheets that match `names(listofdfs)` and the proper values stored within those sheets.

Comment: Same error with your first solution (invalid subscript type 'list'), but the second one works as you said. 
Can I import the sheets individually in R?

Comment: @Anthony, I've made a small reproducible example that works. There are many ways you can import the sheets of an excel file. You can specify a specific sheet using `readxl::read_excel` or you can import the entire workbook into a `list` object where the list names are the sheet names using `rio::import_list`, for example.

Comment: Indeed, it worked with the iris dataset, still not with mine. I'll try to figure this out.
The readxl solution will do the job. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Anthony you're welcome. Unfortunately, without seeing more of your structure I cannot determine what is causing your issue.