# How can I write out multiple files with different filenames in R

Tags: r, filenames, multiple-tables

I have one BIG file (>10000 lines of data) and I want write out a separate file by ID.  I have 50 unique ID names and I want a separate text file for each one.  Here's what Ive got so far, and I keep getting errors.  My ID is actually character string which I would prefer if I can name each file after that character string it would be best.

```
for (i in 1:car$ID) {
    a <- data.frame(car[,i])
    carib <- car1[,(c("x","y","time","sd"))]
    myfile <- gsub("( )", "", paste("C:/bridge", carib, "_", i, ".txt"))
    write.table(a, file=myfile,
                sep="", row.names=F, col.names=T quote=FALSE, append=FALSE) 
}
```

Comment: The code you've written is very problematic to interpret.  It's hard to tell if ID is really a column in car that you want to use.  What data frame holds the data... car1?  What's the difference between it and car?  Which one are you really trying to write out?  Is it supposed to be broken up by column or by row?  What do you really want the file names to be?  Please describe more precisely what you want to do.

Comment: One really obvious question deals with your myfile statement. Is "bridge" part of the desired filename (placing the file on your root directory) or is it supposed to be a directory?

Comment: telling us what the error messages are would probably help too.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411429/is-it-possible-to-use-write-table-and-ddply-together

Comment: I apologize for a poorly worded question.  I didn't know how to present the data in this instance or provide example stuff for you to help with.  The ID column had 50 unique names.  
@bill  The "Bridge" was a directory on the C drive I was trying to work into.  
@John Car1 and car is a mistake.  It should be car for all.  
@Chase, thank you the link helps didn't realize it was a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use the plyr package and the `d_ply()` function. `d_ply()` expects a data.frame as an input. You also provide a column(s) that you want to slice and dice that data.frame by to operate on independently of one another. In this case, you have the column ID. This specific function does not return an object, and is thus useful for plotting, or making charter iteratively, etc. Here's a small working example:

```
library(plyr)

dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(letters[1:3],2) , x = rnorm(6), y = rnorm(6))

d_ply(dat, "ID", function(x)
     write.table(x, file = paste(x$ID[1], "txt", sep = "."), sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE))
```

Will generate three tab separates files with the ID column as the name of the files (a.txt, b.txt, c.txt).

**EDIT - to address follow up question**

You could always subset the columns you want before passing it into `d_ply()`. Alternatively, you can use/abuse the `[` operator and select the columns you want within the call itself:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(letters[1:3],2) , x = rnorm(6), y = rnorm(6)
  , foo = rnorm(6))

d_ply(dat, "ID", function(x)
     write.table(x[, c("x", "foo")], file = paste(x$ID[1], "txt", sep = ".")
     , sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: This worked great.  Do you think there is a way to pick out specific variables instead of all the variables from the file?  Meaning, in this example you gave an X and Y, but say you had a Z variable in there too, but didn't want it to be in the final output...how would you only select the X and Y to be exported from this dataframe?

Comment: @Kerry - provided another example to follow up on your Q.

Comment: no need my man! what you provided is right.  I just couldn't figure out where to put the [].  Im learning thanks to you!  Thank you so much, it worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 2):

For the data frame called `mtcars` separated by `mtcars$cyl`:

```
lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl), 
   function(x)write.table(x, file = paste(x$cyl[1], ".txt", sep = "")))
```

This produces "4.txt", "6.txt", "8.txt" with the corresponding data. This should be faster than looping/subsetting since the subsetting (splitting) is vectorized.

Comment: great.  this worked too.  I appreciate all of the advice you guys are giving!  Thank you so much!