# How to use the apply family instead of for loops?

Tags: r

I have a very specific question on how to avoid for loops. I have a function writeone which writes data into a file, and the following two nested for loops:

```
for(i in 1:(ntaxa-1)){
print(i)
 for(j in (i+1):ntaxa){
 writeone(taxa[i],taxa[j])
 }
}
```

The printing element is not necessary but it would be nice to keep it.

Comment: Do not use the `*apply` functions for this. They are designed for situations where you need a return value. In such situations they offer a cleaner and more convenient syntax. However, they usually do not improve performance compared to a `for` loop. However, I would challenge the need to write to the file with a loop. Obviously you didn't share all details, but writing to file can probably be done as one step.

Comment: `lapply` can be used to write multiple files instead of `for` loops, keep the data to be written in a list and do something like this `lapply(data.list, function(x) write.table(x, paste(names(x), '.txt', sep=''), sep='\t')`

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683390/how-can-i-write-out-multiple-files-with-different-filenames-in-r) too