# Write multiple files from R data

Tags: r

I am trying to create multiple files based on unique ID's in the dataset. I have tried [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683390/how-can-i-write-out-multiple-files-with-different-filenames-in-r) as well as [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411429/is-it-possible-to-use-write-table-and-ddply-together?lq=1).

For the first option, I am getting an error

```
d_ply(ec, ec$BPID, function(x)
   write.table(file = paste(x$ID, "txt", sep = ".")
               , sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE))
```

Error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a46' not found
```

The ID is alphanumeric, so some may have a letter, and after sorting I see that 'a46' is the first alphanumeric ID without all values being numeric.

For the second option, the code runs but there is no output. I also tried to create a dictionary using the unique values for the ID column here.

```
a <- unique(df$ID)
d_ply(df, .(a),
      function(sdf) write.csv(sdf,
                              file=paste(sdf$a[[1]],".csv",sep="")))
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you provide a subset of the `ec` data frame that will reproduce the error?

Comment: The second argument to the `d?ply` functions is a quoted column name. Try `d_ply(df, .(ID), ...)` for your second example and `d_ply(ec, .(BPID), ...)` for your first.