# Writing to a filename that varies depending on a variable in R

Tags: r, filenames

Using R in Windows 7

I have a program that creates a big matrix called patients.  It also has a variable called filenum.  I would like to write the file to a table that varies based on filenum.  For instance, if filenum = 1, I'd like it to write out to

"c:\personal\output1"

How can I do this?

I've been playing with paste and a little with gsub, but I can't get this to work

Thanks in advance

Peter

Comment: Peter - see this question for a plyr solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411429/is-it-possible-to-use-write-table-and-ddply-together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this via `lapply(split(), write.table, ...)` or the equivalent function from plyr, but it would probably be fastest and cleanest to do this with a for loop.  Something like:

```
for(fnum in unique(patients[,"filenum"])) {
  set <- which(patients[,"filenum"] == fnum)
  write.table(patients[set,], paste("c:/personal/output",fnum,sep=""))
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was quick.  Did just what I wanted, too.